# How to clear scons cache? CheckLibWithHeader returns "no" first time called, "yes" second time

Tags: scons

I have a SConstruct file that is checking for the Google protobuf library, like so:

```
main['HAVE_PROTOBUF'] = main['PROTOC'] and \
conf.CheckLibWithHeader('protobuf', 'google/protobuf/message.h',
                        'C++', 'GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;')
```

I noticed that this call to CheckLibWithHeader was returning "no". I was doing some debugging of the script, and it became apparent to me that subsequent identical calls to CheckLibWithHeader returned "yes". When I put an identical line in the SConstruct file immediately following the one above, the output was as follows:

```
.
.
.
Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library None... (cached) yes
Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z... (cached) yes
Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... (cached) no
Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... (cached) yes
Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... no
Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library rt... yes
.
.
.
```

I do have the protobuf libraries. Does anyone know why the first call to CheckLibWithHeader is returning "no"?

This problem for me occurs in CentOS, but not in Ubuntu.

Update: I am no longer able to reproduce the above problem. However, I have found that when I run into a problem with scons using a value marked as "(cached)" that appears to be incorrect, I can do two things to help get to a solution. I'll put these in an answer below.

Comment: In order to make your observation repeatable, could you reduce your SConstruct to the smallest possible SConstruct that still demonstrates the error (3 lines or so?) and copy-paste that short SConstruct in its entirety into your question? See http://SSCCE.org or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I figured out what the problem was. I will post the solution.

Comment: Well, to correct myself: I found away around the problem.

Comment: After thinking about it, this question is actually dealing with two separate problems. One is the question of why scons returns different values from consecutive calls to CheckLibWithHeader. The other is the question of why the protobuf packages in CentOS don't include gzip_stream.h. I was able to get around the second problem. I am still not sure about the first question, but it appears to have something to do with scons's caching mechanisms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `--config=force` command line option should re-run all configuration tests without looking at the cached results. According to the [man page for SCons](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html):

```
--config=force

If this option is specified, all configuration tests will be re-run
regardless of whether the cached results are out of date. This can 
be used to explicitly force the configuration tests to be updated in
response to an otherwise unconfigured change in a system header file 
or compiler.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when I run into a problem with scons using a value marked as "(cached)" that appears to be incorrect, I can do two things to help solve the problem.

1. Check the "config.log" file, which shows what actions scons is actually taking when it is running its checks. This will provide hints as to why the check is failing.
2. Delete the file ".sconsign.dblite" and the directory ".sconf_temp". This appears to clear out the scons cache, as during the following builds the "(cached)" markings don't appear.